# MySQL foreign key?

Tags: mysql

i have two mysql tables,appointments and users...my idea was when user logs in and makes an appointment to store that appointment in his user profile so he can cancel that specific appointment later,so as i said i have two tables with primary keys named id...how can i show appointments in user profile?because i already made these 2 tables i used alter table to add foreign key appointment_id in user table,query went well but nothing changed...i'm kinda new in this so any help would be appreciated...

i'm sorry for not posting tables,im new...here they are...this is actually not my code,its joomla component code,now as i said when user logs in and makes an appointment i want user to be able to go to his user profile and there see all appointments that he has made,maybe this can be done other way but my idea was using foreign key in tables...

USERS

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `username` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `usertype` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `block` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `sendEmail` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
 `registerDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `lastvisitDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `activation` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `params` text NOT NULL,
 `lastResetTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Date of last password reset',
 `resetCount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Count of password resets since lastResetTime',
 `fk_appointments` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `usertype` (`usertype`),
 KEY `idx_name` (`name`),
 KEY `idx_block` (`block`),
 KEY `username` (`username`),
 KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=574 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

APPOINTMENTS

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_jxtc_appbook_appointments` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `checked_out` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `checked_out_time` datetime NOT NULL,
 `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `published` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `email` tinytext NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `duration` time NOT NULL,
 `start` time NOT NULL,
 `end` time NOT NULL,
 `field1` text NOT NULL,
 `field2` text NOT NULL,
 `field3` text NOT NULL,
 `field4` text NOT NULL,
 `field5` text NOT NULL,
 `field6` text NOT NULL,
 `field7` text NOT NULL,
 `field8` text NOT NULL,
 `field9` text NOT NULL,
 `field10` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=309 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Show your table structures for better answers

Comment: Not enough information. How are you retrieving the data, say, the query you're using?

Comment: Well, just adding a column as key does not magically insert values. You have to use it in your application. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually i made a new value in my table userident-int and inside the form i made a new input that will store the id of the user that submitted that form...

```
<input type="hidden" name="userident" ide="userident" value="<?php $user =& JFactory::getUser(); echo $user->id; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select * from appointments where user.id=appointment.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a join:

```
select * from users u, appointments a where u.appointment_id=a.id
```